# Is it possible to create photo events from the Camera Roll photo's on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I see that the Photos app let's me create Albums, but is it possible to create and manage Photo Events on the iPhone without iTunes or iPhoto* on a Mac/PC?

*I say *iPhoto on a Mac/PC* because the iPhoto iOS app doesn't appear to allow it either:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I believe the iPhoto app does allow it.

Comment: @AceLegend - how? - please elaborate on your comment, and post it as an answer!

Comment: That's the trouble. I believe I saw someone do it somewhere, but I am not positive. I do not have the iPhoto app, therefore I can not verify this claim. Just thought I would throw it out in case anyone else has used this app.